# How to use the Rails 2.3 app generator when I have Rails 3 installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

to clarify: there's only one `rails` command, which gets installed from the latest Rails gem, which is Rails 3 ATM. However, I'm required to create a Rails 2.3 app.

Running `ruby /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/bin/rails` fails with a NoMethodError, I suppose because it also tries to use gems from the 3.0.0 release.

Uninstalling the gem produces some strange results:

```
$ gem uninstall rails-3.0.0  
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d rails-3.0.0`

$ gem list -d rails-3.0.0  

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
(and no gems here)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do it was:

1. Create the directory for the project
2. Create a `Gemfile` there containing

   ```
   gem "rails", "2.3.9"
   gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
   ```
3. Run `bundle install`
4. Run `bundle exec rails .` to create an app in the current path

You don't even need rvm to do this.

Answer (score 2):

(I assume 2.3.11, given it's the latest)

`rails _2.3.11_ new app` will do this for you without you having to muck about.

Answer (score 1):

*(Had to make a comment since I don't have enough Stack Overflow cred and can't directly respond to answers yet.)*

For folks running rails 3 now the "new" command is now required for creating new rails applications. As such "new" will need to be appended to the end of the commands.

So for Leonid Shevtsov's answer, Step 4: `bundle exec rails new .`

And for Robert Speicher's answer: `rails new .`

Answer (score 0):

Install [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and then create a new [gemset](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/), so that Rails 2 is isolated.

Or, go to the directory where you want your Rails 2 app to be, create a Gemfile like a Rails 3 app, but specify `gem "rails", "~> 2.3"` and run `bundle install`, and you should now be able to issue `rails .`

Comment: Not `rails .`, but `bundle exec rails .` - bundles aren't picked up by default.