# How can I create previous version rails in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just upgraded my rails version to rails 3.0.
But suddenly I need a new rails app with old version of rails.
I know the new version of rails change command line usage with `rails new`.
How can I create an old version of Rails in this new Rails 3 environment?

Answer (score 14):

Use the following command:

```
rails _2.3.5_ new APP_NAME
```

This will create a rails project with version 2.3.5

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 12):

Leonid Shevtsov provided instructions for how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706914/how-to-use-the-rails-2-3-app-generator-when-i-have-rails-3-installed/3706970#3706970).

The easiest way to do it was:

> 1. Create the directory for the project
> 2. Create a `Gemfile` there containing
>
>    `gem "rails", "2.3.9"`
>
>    `gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"`
> 3. Run`bundle install`
> 4. Run `bundle exec rails .` to create an app in the current path
>
> You don't even need rvm to do this.

Comment: This might be a recent change, but I had to change step 4 to `bundle exec rails new .` to create the rails app

Comment: newer versions of bundler use `source 'https://rubygems.org'` to specify (more secure) sources. Edited step 2. :) I used this post to install 3.2.13 from 4.0.0-rc1

Answer (score 0):

If you need to switch back and forth, I would recommend  using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).  You can install different versions of Ruby and each can have its own set of gems.  I use my system installed ruby (1.8.6?) on my Mac for Rails 2 dev, and then I installed Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM for my Rails 3 dev.  Its as simple as doing this after you have RVM installed:

```
#install and use 1.9.2 for Rails 3
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm 1.9.2
rails new whatever

#switch back to system installed ruby for Rails 2
rvm system
rails whatever
```