# How can I generate older rails application when current version is 3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 different Rails Rubygems installed on my Linux OS [2.3.8 and 3.0.3], but the current active Rails version is 3.0.3. So is it possible to generate Rails app using 2.3.8 style generator:`rails testapp` not new one: `rails new testapp`?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706914/how-to-use-the-rails-2-3-app-generator-when-i-have-rails-3-installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend installing [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and setting up different [gemsets](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/) for each version of Rails. That way you can easily switch between Rails versions by just switching gemsets.

Comment: Invest the time in learning RVM if you have to use different versions of Rails.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell Rails to use version `2.3.8` like this:

```
rails _2.3.8_ testapp
```

Answer (score 1):

See here: [How to use the Rails 2.3 app generator when I have Rails 3 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706914/how-to-use-the-rails-2-3-app-generator-when-i-have-rails-3-installed)

Quoting [Leonid Shevtsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6678/leonid-shevtsov):

> The easiest way to do it was:
>
> 1. Create the directory for the project
> 2. Create a Gemfile there containing
>         gem "rails", "2.3.9"
>         gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
> 3. Run "bundle install"
> 4. Run "bundle exec rails ." to create an app in the current path
>      You don't even need rvm to do this.

You could also use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).